# Spring batch run exception throwable method after each tasklet done in afterstep()

Tags: java, exception, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

```java
public class TaskletConfiguration {

  ...

  @Bean
  public Step step() {
    return steps.get("step")
        .tasklet(tasklet)
        .exceptionHandler(logExceptionHandler()) // Handler for logging exception to specific channel
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Job job() {
    return jobs.get("job")
        .start(step())
        .build();
  }
}

public class ExampleTasklet implements Tasklet, StepExecutionListener {

  ...

  @Override
  public RepeatStatus execute(...) throws Exception {
    // Do my tasklet
    // Throw if it fails, and be handled by logExceptionHandler()
  }

  @Override
  public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    // Want to throw so that logExceptionHandler() can handle it as throwing in execute().
    throwable_function();
  }
}
```

This is my example code using tasklet in spring boot.
My problem is: I want to throw exception from `afterstep()`, but the interface does not allow it.

Despite this limitation, why I obsessed with `afterstep()` is that I want to make abstract class to make Tasklet template which can verify each execution in `afterstep()`. I want verification to run after all `execute()` is done, which will be overridden by subclass. So I have no choices but using `afterstep()`.

Any idea to run verification method after each `execute()` with throwable or `afterstep()` can pass Exception to `logExceptionHandler()`? I hope to define `logExceptionHandler()` in `TaskletConfiguration` class. It will be obese if it is defined in Tasklet class, as I will make abstract class, which will be inherited by many subclasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `StepExecutionListener#afterStep` is not designed to throw checked exceptions. Here is an excerpt from its Javadoc:

```
Called after execution of step's processing logic (both successful or failed).
Throwing exception in this method has no effect, it will only be logged.
```

Moreover, even if you throw a (runtime) exception in `afterStep`, the exception won't be passed to the exception handler, it will only be logged as mentioned in the Javadoc.

I think it is too late to throw exceptions in `StepExecutionListener#afterStep`, this method can be used to check the status of the step execution and  modify the ExitStatus if needed to drive the rest of the job execution flow.

Comment: I understand your point is that `afterStep` is not designed for do the thing with checked exception. Thanks. Then, how can I make all subclasses of the abstract class call the same method (verification method in the text) at the end?

Comment: You are expecting to use the exception handler in `StepExecutionListener#afterStep`, but as mentioned, this won't work. So `afterStep` is not suitable for you. You can add a protected method in your tasklet and call it inside `execute`. Subclasses can then only override that method.